# How to create bot command that give role to mentioned user | Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to create a Discord bot command.

For example, I would like to create a warning command. So the admin would enter the following command:

```
?Warn @user "<A warning message>"
```

The command will then check if the targeted user (`@user`) has certain roles (for example, "A", "B", "C" and "D"). If he doesn't have the "A" role he will get it, if he has A, he gets B and so on.

The admin must have the "Staff Team" role to use the command.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
#Warning
@bot.command(name="Warn", pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Staff Team")
async def addrole(ctx,arg):
    user = arg
    if user.role.name != "Warning 1" or "Warning 2" or "Warning 3":
        role = get(user.server.roles, name="Warning 1")
        await bot.add_roles(user, role)
    elif user.role.name == "Warning 1":
        role = get(user.server.roles, name="Warning 2")
        role_last = get(user.server.roles, name="Warning 1")
        await bot.add_roles(user, role)
        await bot.remove_roles(user,role_last)
    elif user.role.name == "Warning 2":
        role = get(user.server.roles, name="Warning 3")
        role_last = get(user.server.roles, name="Warning 2")
        await bot.add_roles(user, role)
        await bot.remove_roles(user,role_last)
```

Then the bot DMs the user with text and then the message.

Comment: A user can have several roles, so you can't just check for user.role, but something like ``role_object in user.roles``

Comment: So how I can do that? However how I can ascribe  mentioned user to variable? Cant I ascribe users roles to temp list?

Comment: You have a common Python gotcha on line 5 (you have to have complete instructions on both sides of the logical operator)

Comment: At least somebody will tell me how to assign it mentioned user to variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is anwser:

1. async def Warn(ctx, args1: discord.Member, args2 = "no reason"):

   ```
                     ^                         ^
                User Mention              Optional
   ```
2. Member = args1
3. Role = ctx.guild.get_role(ROLE ID)
4. for roles in Member.roles:
5. if roles != Role: or if roles == Role:
6. await Member.add_roles(Role)

Comment: I hope everybody get it!